# How to find the locus from a general point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, locus

Given a general point on a line, say $\left(\frac35x \ ; {2 \over 5}(x+3)\right)$ or any other general point, how can you find the locus as this point moves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Set $ b= \frac 25 (x+3), \, a = \frac 35 x$ and try to eliminate $x$. This will lead us to an equation between $a,b$. This equation reveals the locus of the points of the form $(a,b)$.

Comment: You're welcome!!